# Fetching rows added last hour

Tags: mysql, datetime, date-range

I keep a record of logins in a table. I have columns for id, ip, date and time. From that record of logins I wanna fetch logins made only in the last hour.

I'm sweeping through the MySQL docs on time and date functions, but I just can't seem to combine them correctly.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Is that four or three columns, and what is the data type of the "date and time"?

Comment: Changed it now, only one column for date and time - and its datetime.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Make use of the [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) and [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) functions:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from  log
where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Hope it helps you : )

Comment: Yes, I did something like that, only with TIMESUB (or SUBTIME?). But does this require that the date-field is a datetime-type?

Comment: Yes using TIMESUB is more appropiate. yes, the first expression has to be a datetime expression. the second one should be a time expression. check this out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime

Comment: Saving data in UTC, it is necessary to use UTC_TIMESTAMP() instead of NOW().

Comment: That would work great but only for quick queries. This would be tricky if you want to make sure you're getting data precisely. For example, if I have a script that runs every hour, I can't just say get me the last hour data because the script might have slight variations in the time when it starts. So I have to set the time range from 13:00:00 to 13:59:59 instead of date > 1 hour ago when it is 2pm

Answer (score 14):

If you want to implement this into a cronjob, you need to specify the start and end.

For example, at 2pm, if you want to get the data for the past hour from 13:00:00 until 13:59:59, here's how to do it:

```
dateField BETWEEN 
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') 
AND 
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d %H:59:59')
```

Answer (score 8):

it can be done easily using

```
select count(*) from logins where datetime>= NOW()- INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend have one datetime column instead of date and time columns.

Suppose you have a datetime column called last_login:

```
SELECT id, ip_address, last_login
FROM mytable
WHERE last_login >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour);
```

Comment: What if the date for a particular day needs to be printed ?. I dont wanna fetch date for the previous day, rather the present day dates only. Can you help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

without the specifics, I think Date_Add() would work.. by adding to your where clause an add of NOW negative hours

(or Date_Sub() )

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CURDATE()function

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS TotalCount
FROM
    tblName
WHERE
    datetime >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Comment: No. That will give the last hour of the previous day.