# How to select last hour without timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

I would like to select all records from the last hour. Problem is, that I don't have an timestamp. I save the time in one row, and in another the date.

```
date        time
2015-11-27  10:55:04
2015-11-27  11:16:38
2015-11-27  11:57:29
2015-11-27  13:04:47
2015-11-27  14:29:00
2015-11-27  14:36:41
2015-11-27  14:52:46
2015-11-27  15:06:20
2015-11-27  15:30:24
2015-11-27  15:47:15
```

Is it possible to convert this to a timestamp in order to make the selection i wish according to this method:
[select rows from last 2 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681345/mysql-fetching-rows-added-last-hour)

thanks!

Comment: what have you tried sofar? And what are the datatypes of the date and time column?

Comment: 1. (Obviously) Consider storing date and time as as single entity

Comment: Your google search string is `mysql date functions`.

Comment: This convert datetime column like this select convert(datetime,'2015-11-27 '+' 10:55:04')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I could solve the problem by myself.
Thanks for your hints.

```
SELECT *
FROM recs
WHERE TIMESTAMP(`datefield`,`timefield`) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND NOW();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share other way around,

```
SELECT 
        * 
FROM
        <tablename>
WHERE 
        CAST(CONCAT(datecolumn,' ',timecolumn) AS DATETIME) > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```