# compare time in EDT in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

This is my first shell script and I need some help.

The shell script needs to extract specific rows from the table based on **startingTime** column. The **startingTime** column has time in this format 
'2016-05-16T13:12:22.089EDT.

Now, I am able to connect to db(supports SQL) via the script able to fetch the data using the below query:

```
select a,b from table1;
```

however, I need to change it this format:

```
select a,b from table1 where startingTime >(NOW() - 2 hours)
```

however, it doesn't work.

Note:

I tried the below URL trying to use date in specific format but didnt help.

[How to compare two DateTime strings and return difference in hours? (bash shell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116503/how-to-compare-two-datetime-strings-and-return-difference-in-hours-bash-shell)

Also, I tried the below option using DATE_SUB, didn't help.

[MySQL: Fetching rows added last hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681345/mysql-fetching-rows-added-last-hour)

Answer (score 0):

Following changes worked:

```
dt2=`date -v-120+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.M`
```

and

```
select a,b from table1 where startingTime > '$dt2';
```