# Fetching rows with updated at timestamp older than 1 day in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I have a table with schema as follows:

```
mysql> desc a;
  +---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at    | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

In `updated_at` I capture timestamp.

Now I would like to fetch all rows with `updated_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

To do this, I have written following query taking idea from [Fetching rows added last hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681345/fetching-rows-added-last-hour):

```
mysql> select count(*) from a where DATE(updated_at) < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

Though there are many rows with updated at with 2 years old timestamp, I am getting 0 here.

Comment: What sort of values are in `updated_at`?

Comment: @Nick timestamp values are in updated_at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `DATE` on an integer timestamp value; you must convert it to a `DATE` using [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM a
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(updated_at) < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Note that you don't have to use `DATE_SUB` to subtract an interval, you can just write the arithmetic directly.